# MSSQL format time format value from certain column

Tags: sql-server

Using SQL Server 2008R2

Lets say I run the following query with the example value as output:

Query:

```
select name, crdate 
from master.dbo.sysdatabases
```

Output:

```
master  2003-04-08 09:13:36.390
tempdb  2016-03-17 19:47:41.990
model   2003-04-08 09:13:36.390
msdb    2010-04-02 17:35:08.970
```

How can I change the output formats of the time values?

Example:

```
master  2003-04-08 09:13:36
```

or

```
master 04-08-2003 09:13
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use ...

```
select name,DATEADD(ms, -DATEPART(ms, crdate), crdate)
from master.dbo.sysdatabases
```

Or use another option is :-

```
select name,CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), crdate, 120))
from master.dbo.sysdatabases
```

I Think this is helpful.

Answer (score -1):

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx#Anchor_3) is the reference for time conversion styles.
[Another link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx) for custom formats documentation.

Example for the second case:

`select name, FORMAT(crdate, 'MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm', 'en-US') AS 'crdate'
from master.dbo.sysdatabases`

Comment: Why dont you fully document the answer so one does not have to leave StackOverflow?

Comment: You want me to copy the content from a sql server documentation because you don't want to click the link? Ok: `CONVERT ( data_type [ ( length ) ] , expression [ , style ] )`. You need to use appropriate `style` value to get the converted value

Comment: Not because I dont want to click, certain links don't stay valid, would be a shame if the link died in the future. Plus, I am a total SQL newbie so an answer with       an _example_ would be really great, just providing a link that I have looked up a couple of times does not really help me out. ;)